# why Google API Key disabled?

Tags: google-places-api

I wrote sample application for get particular place details near by user.
i got API KEY but I have one problem with key.when ever i insert the key in in my code.I got error. that error is The provided key is not a valid Google API key,or it is not authorized for the Google maps java script API v3 on this site.

my code is running fine without any key.
any one tell the solution for this key.

thanks in advance,
swathi.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) does not require an API key to implement however using an API key enables you to monitor your application's Maps API usage, and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary.

If you wish to use an API Key you can obtain one by following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key).

Then when include the Maps API JavaScript in your code insert your API Key.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```